# DevXpress Report Designer using Python

Tags: python-3.x

How can I access the DevXpress Report Generator using python code?

I have some data in excel. Using Python I want to feed that data in particular muster like Report in Devxpress. in Devxpress  I have choice to create a form using different active controls.

But I don't have any idead, how can I achieve it.